# Loading another stylesheet with Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have made a website in Joomla. The design is really dependent by the background image, so I need to have an image for every screen resolution. 
I have heard there is an easy way to do this, for example adding a `<link>` tag to the head section. But I dont know how. 
And secondly I dont know were to put my css file in my FTP direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knock yourself out :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/page-background

Thats what the extension directory is for!